# Are full-coverage questions welcome?

Tags: discussion

Does questions that asks for a full-coverage of some small topic are welcome, or they will be considered *too broad*, and it's better to split them into multiple questions?

For example, a question about how to choose an equipment for a specific need, how to use it and how to maintain it.

What I currently have in mind is about [mate](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mate) - I wanted to share knowledge (ask and answer) about how to choose a mate, the differences, how to prepare one (different methods) and how to maintain it.
Currently, there's one relevant question on part of the topic <sup>[1]</sup>, which I could extend its answers to add more information, and I was wondering how to continue with that.

Thanks!

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> [What is the proper way to make a cup of mate?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6964/66800)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

All of the pieces of that are welcome, but they should be separate questions.

The "too broad" close text is:

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

An "everything about mate" question seems to pretty clearly fall afoul of that.

And as for *why* we have that policy, the biggest part is that when people do ask multiple questions at once, while sometimes we do get comprehensive answers, we often get a bunch of different answers each addressing only part of the question, making it easy for some parts to go unanswered. So it wouldn't be as likely to get the knowledge the question invites as separate questions would anyways. Along with that, it often makes it tougher for future readers to search for and read through.

Some of that is less of an issue for a self-answered question, but at the same time, it makes it even more difficult for others to contribute, so I'm not sure that's a reason to bend the rules.